# Java stream to collection for nullable string list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list that may be null. 
I would like to concatenate the strings in that list into one string.

eg. A
list = ["hello","there"]
desired output = "hello.there."

eg. B
list = null
desired output = null

I have a method that works for non-null lists:

```
List<String> myStringList = foo.getlist();
String result = myStringList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(".","","."));
```

but the stream will throw an error if myStringList is null.

I believe I should be using an optional stream similar to:

```
List<String> myStringList = foo.getlist();
String result = Optional.ofNullable(myStringList)
    .map(Arrays::stream)
    .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(".","","."))
```

However when I try this i get errors like "can not resolve method 'stream'".

Am I going about this the right way?
Why am I getting errors for the code?

Comment: You said, the desired output for a `null` list is “null”. Do you mean the string `"null"` or a `null` reference? Using an empty stream as fallback serves neither…

Comment: I would like to return a null reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **Collections.emptyList()**

1- List not null :

```
List<String> myStringList = new ArrayList<>() ;
            myStringList.add("hello");
            myStringList.add("hello");

            String result = Optional.ofNullable(myStringList).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(".","","."));
            System.out.println(result);
```

output :  `hello.hello.`

2- List null :

```
 List<String> myStringList2 = null;


             result = Optional.ofNullable(myStringList2).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(".","","."));
            System.out.println(result);
```

output :  `.`

you can edit your output if you want

Answer (score 3):

This is a personal opinion, but I think you shouldn't use `Optional` that way. `Optional` is not intended to replace a simple null-check. If you already have the `Optional`, then use it, or use it as the possibly absent return value of a method. Otherwise, I think it's more expressive and readable to show your exact intention w.r.t. the list being `null` or not:

```
List<String> myStringList = foo.getlist();

String result = myStringList == null ? 
        null :
        myStringList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(".","","."));
```

In this cases, the ternary operator does a nice work.

---

**EDIT:**

If the joined string was the return value of a method, then using `Optional` and *returning it* would be a perfect fit:

```
private Optional<String> joinedFooList(Foo foo) {
    List<String> myStringList = foo.getlist();
    return Optional.ofNullable(myStringList)
        .map(l -> l.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(".","",".")));
}
```

Then, you could use the returned `Optional`:

```
joinedFooList(someFooInstance)
        .ifPresent(joined -> /* so something with the joined string */);
```

Comment: The OP’s code would result in `"."` (after fixing the error) when the list is `null` (though the OP said that the intended result is `null`)…

Comment: @Holger Yes, I think the OP is wrong about either his result expectations or his attempt to solve this with streams and optionals, I mean, beyond the error in `Arrays::stream`.

Comment: it would be nice for Java to introduce the _null propagation_ operator, in which case we can do things like `String result = myStringList?.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(".","","."));`, IMO this will reduce `NullPointerException`s as well as reduce `if` statements or nested `if` statements that guard against _nullity_ in many places. I know the `Optional` class does a similar thing but there are certain areas where _null propagation_ is better and more suitable.

Comment: @Aominè Yes, but it wouldn't be java, then. Also the elvis operator `:?` would be nice

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to use `Arrays::stream` to convert your `List` to a stream. But, `Arrays::stream` is for *arrays*.

You need `List::stream` (which is the inherited version of `Collection::stream`, so that one would work too):

```
String result = Optional.ofNullable(myStringList)
    .map(List::stream)
    .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(".","","."));
```

Comment: Yep, that was the error. As pointed out above, it's not a good use of an optional but that's my fault.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If third-party libraries are game, Apache CollectionUtils has a nice utility for making lists null-safe:

```
List<String> myStringList = foo.getlist();
String result = CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(myStringList).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(".","","."));
```